# How to change keyboard layout via keyboard shortcut?

Tags: keyboard, ui, internationalization, shortcut

I like to use both US and German keyboard layout but I find the process of switching between them via mouse tiresome. I want a keyboard-only solution.

Is there a predefined shortcut to change between multiple keyboard layouts, or if not, how could I define such a shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this:

[image: input source]

`Pref panel => Keyboard => shortcuts => Input Sources` then set your shortcut

If you have conflict a small yellow triangle will appear guiding you to the conflict shortcut. (disable or change it)

If the Spotlight appears, disable its shortcut.

Comment: Select next source in input menue is exactly what I was looking for. I prefer for Cmd Space to launch spotlight, so I reverted that command. (That one also uses an overlay I do not want to use.)